# Activity Indicator not Spinning when Pulled the tableView to Refresh in Xcode using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have written the code to refresh the viewController whenever the tableView is pulled. But, whenever I pull the tableView to refresh the page, the activity indicator is shown but, it is not spinning. Would appreciate it if anyone could please help me out with this issue? Thanks for the help!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

    }

    @objc func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {
       // Code to refresh table view
    
        loadData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a completion to `loadData` as it's an asynchronous method

```
loadData() { 
  self.refreshControl.endRefreshing() 
}
```

With

```
func loadData(completion:@escaping(() -> ())) {
  Api.load {
       completion()
  }
}
```

Comment: Or, if you're just testing, just use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { loadData() }`